For an ideal Kalman filter, I have that the NEES test passes but NIS test does not?
Sorry if this is more of a debugging question, but I have been stuck on this supposedly simple NIS test for a very long while. If anyone knows any sources which cover the theory or implementation of the NIS test, I would definitely appreciate any links.
So, I am just running a very straight forward Kalman filter on a toy problem to check my understanding. I have the LTI discrete system
$x_{k+1}=F x_k+w_k$
$y_k=Hx_k+v_k$
where $w_k \sim N(0,\sigma_w^2)$ and $v_k \sim N(0,\sigma_v^2)$ are the white process and measurement noise respectively with covariances $Q$ and $R$.
These are used to generate the true state $x_k$ and the obtained measurement $y_k$ (I am just using mvnrnd in MATLAB to obtain the white noise samples).
Then, I am also running the straightforward Kalman filter equations. With an initial state error covariance $\hat{P}_0$ and an initial corrected state vector $\hat{x}_0$ I then can integrate these forward using
$\tilde P_k=\hat{P}_{k-1}$
$\tilde x_k=F \hat{x}_{k-1}$
$K_k=\tilde P_k H^T (H \tilde P_k H^T +R )^{-1}$
$\hat{P}_k=(1-K_k H) \tilde P_k (1-K_k H)^T + K_k R K_k^T$
$\hat{x}_k=\tilde{x}_k+K_k(y_k-H \tilde x_k) $
Then, I perform a NIS test to ascertain its consistency following section 2.2.3 in the lecture notes here:
https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~ian/Teaching/Estimation/LectureNotes2.pdf
To do this, I formulate the innovation covariance
$S_k=H \hat{P}_k H^T + R$
from which I formulate the normalized innovation error
$e_k=[H(x_k-\hat{x}_k)]^T S_k^{-1} [H(x_k-\hat{x}_k)]$.
Doing an $N$ trial Monte Carlo run and with the measurement having $m$ elements, I can get for every $k^{th}$ timestep the average normalized innovation error across all of the Monte Carlo runs as $\bar{e}_k$, and from the sources I saw we should have that $N \bar{e}_k$ follows a Chi squared distribution with $N*m$ degrees of freedom.
So, apparently with $\alpha=0.05$ I should have around 95% of $\bar{e}_k$ lie in the bounds $[r_1,r_2]$ obtained using the MATLAB commands
$r_1=chi2inv(alpha/2,N*m)/N$
$r_2=chi2inv(1-alpha/2,N*m)/N$
However, I always have $\bar{e}_k$ being way below the computed error bounds. I did the very similar NEES test and those pass without issue, and I double checked the lecture notes and other sources, made sure my computed Chi squared bounds matched the ones in the lecture notes, and I even tried multiple different expressions for $P$ and $S$, but so far nothing has worked for the NIS test. I was wondering is the above correct, and does anyone have any sources for the NIS test? Sorry again for the rambling debugging question.

Wow, fixed it. Just in case anyone else runs into this headache, you need to use the actual noisy measurement and the a priori uncorrected state estimate. So, using
$e_k=[y_k-H \tilde x_k]^T S_k^{-1} [y_k-H \tilde x_k]$
